# python-flask: pluggable views for dynamic routes

Tags: python, flask

i'm developing an api which is basically a wrapper to make rpc calls.
how do i go about making my script more dynamic and robust?

i want to be able to dynamically call a method with optional parameters, without creating a new route for every possible call option...maybe with pluggable views or a custom decorated function.

i am quite new to this; and am pretty sure i'm missing something obvious that prevents me from getting it.

```
   from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, url_for
    from a_module import some_class

    mc  = some_class(object)

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/get_data/', defaults={'var1' : 'a', 'var2' : 'b'}, methods=['GET'])
    @app.route('/get_data/<var1>', defaults={'var2' : ''} , methods=['GET'])
    @app.route('/get_data/<var1>.<var2>', methods=['GET'])
    def get_data(var1, var2):
        data = mc.some_fn(var1, var2)
        return jsonify({'get_data:': data})

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

thanks

Comment: you should use querystring, and get the data like `request.GET.get('var1', 'a')`, this is django style, flask must have something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.route('/get_data/', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    var1 = request.args.get('var1', 'a')
    var2 = request.args.get('var2', 'b')
    data = mc.some_fn(var1, var2)
    return jsonify({'get_data:': data})
```

use jquery:

```
$.get(base_url+'/get_data/', {'var1':'aaa', 'var2': 'bbb'})
```

the request path is:

```
/get_data/?var1=aaa&var2=bbb
```